# Getting 403 Access Forbidden error in Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I have Academic access in twitter and i have written the following code to check if it is working.

```
import tweepy
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
query = '#BLM -is:retweet'
start_time = '2020-05-01T00:00:00Z'
end_time = '2020-07-01T00:00:00Z'
tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations','created_at'],
                                  start_time=start_time,
                                  end_time=end_time, max_results=10)
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.created_at)
```

Im getting the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweet_scrapper.py", line 13, in <module>
    tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'],
  File "tweepy/client.py", line 699, in search_all_tweets
    return self._make_request(
  File "/tweepy/client.py", line 166, in _make_request
    response = self.request(method, route, params=request_params,
  File "/tweepy/client.py", line 124, in request
    raise Forbidden(response)
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this a bearer token that you generated on your account?

Comment: Try using the v1 API and verify that the authentication is working: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/examples.html